# api calls one after other one the base of first Api response

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

**I have a situation like follows.**

1. I have to call one api which will give me the list of restaurants ids.
2. Call Api for each restaurant and get information one by one

Help me with Rx-java solution for this or if you have great solution for this let me know.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical scenario for [flatMap](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#flatMap-rx.functions.Func1-)

you just need to call the api for the restaurants and flatMap the response. Let's say you have the class

```
data class Restaurant(val id)
```

If the api returns a `Single<List<Restuarant>>` for example, then you can easily flat map it:

```
  getListOfRestaurants()
    .flatMapObservable { Observable.fromIterable(it) }
    .flatMap { getRestaurantDetails(it.id) }
    .toList()
```

Doing `fromIterable` helps out to emit each restaurant at a time and then with `flatMap` you can easily get the details.

The `toList()` is optional, it's only if you want the restaurant details as a list.

Comment: For getRestaurantDetails(it.id) I am taking Single but it gives me problem type mismatch, when I make it like getRestaurantDetails(it.id).toObservable() it works fine but I get disposable to dispose it

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood. Are using `flatMapObservable`?

Comment: I see, the return of `getRestaurantDetails()` is a single? In this case, `toObervable()` is a good solution, but I don't understand how you are getting a disposable and not an observable

Answer (score 0):

1. Call API to get `Observable<List<String>>`
2. Create a list of Observables to get restaurants:

```
    val restaurantsObservables: List<Observable<Restaraunt>> 
            = ids.map { getRestaurantById(it) } 

    Observable.concat(Observable.from(restaurantsObservables)).toList()
```

`Observable.from(restaurantsObservables)` - it will transform source sequence into Observable that emits each item from sequence.

`Observable.concat(...)` - it will make requests to be executed sequentially.

`.toList()` part will collect all responses in one `Observable<List<Restaurant>>`